# Möbius transformation change of the variables formula on the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the Möbius map $$\varphi_{a}(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a}z}$$for $a,z\in\mathbb{D}$.

I'm trying to prove the following change of the variables formula on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(\varphi_a(e^{i\theta})) \, d\theta =\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\frac{1-|a|^2}{|1-ae^{-it}|^2} \, dt$$ for all $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T},d\theta)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What has this to do with `functional-analysis`?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Apologies, I just edited the tag.

Comment: what is $\varphi_{a}'(z)$?

Comment: @Conrad it would be $\varphi'_{a}(z)=\frac{-1+|a|^{2}}{(1-\bar{a}z)^{2}}$

Comment: But now if $\varphi_{a}(e^{i\theta})=e^{it}$ we get that $ i\varphi_{a}'(e^{i\theta})e^{i\theta}d\theta=ie^{it}dt$ can you continue from there?

Comment: @Conrad How can I incorporate the derivative here? Would you be able to give me a little more hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi_{a}(e^{i\theta})=e^{it}$ hence $\frac{a-e^{i\theta}}{1-\bar{a}e^{i\theta}}=e^{it}$ which leads to $\frac{a-e^{it}}{1-\bar{a}e^{it}}=e^{i\theta}$, hence taking differentials:

$\frac{-1+|a|^{2}}{(1-\bar{a}e^{it})^{2}}ie^{it}dt=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$ and substituting in terms of $t$, we get:

$d\theta=\frac{-1+|a|^{2}}{(1-\bar{a}e^{it})^{2}}\frac{1-\bar{a}e^{it}}{a-e^{it}}e^{it}dt$ or by simplification

$d\theta=\frac{-1+|a|^{2}}{(1-\bar a e^{it})(ae^{-it}-1)}dt=\frac{1-|a|^2}{|1-ae^{-it}|^2}dt$ so the change of variables follows by substituting $d\theta$ (since by defintion $ f(\varphi_a(e^{i\theta}))=f(e^{it})$, while the bounds remain same by periodicity) and we are done!

(note that in the OP, RHS is an integral in $t$ so the denominator must be $|1-ae^{-it}|^2$)

Comment: Why is $\varphi_a(e^{i \theta})$ equal to a unit complex number?

Comment: @user $\varphi_{a}(e^{i\theta})=\frac{a-e^{i\theta}}{1-\bar{a}e^{i\theta}}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{a-e^{i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}-\bar{a}}=-e^{-i\theta}\frac{w}{\bar w}$ so taking absolute values we get $1$ as $|w|=|\bar w|$